# Run Android on virtual machine for development

Tags: android

Currently I am using Android emulator for development, but it is very slow. I am looking for some android port that can run on real CPU.

For example I installed this product http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto on VMware, and it seems to work much faster, but I have no idea how to setup network connection here.

The question is if some one is using alternative android setup for development, instead of emulator? If so, a link to configure instructions would be great.

Comment: If you leave the emulator running, it's pretty tolerable.

Android x86 is probably not the best for developing for handsets. It's probably cool if you're interested in the future, and I do really anticipate stable android on netbooks. That will be the day!
note: i know it is already on netbooks, I mean production ready.

Comment: I know that emulator should not be closed, but it is still very slow for me. So I would like to have it running on real CPU and not on the emulated ARM. The final testing I can always do on emulator.

Comment: Maybe it's the computer that you're running it on? The android emulator is pretty good on my computer, even my laptop seems to run it decently. Also, unless I'm mistaken, the emulator tries to give an accurate representation of android hardware. So it doesn't run it with the full power of your computer (like the iphone emulator)

Comment: I am using Core 2 duo, 2.0 GHz. What I have noticed, it always using only one core, thought there are 2 cores available. I also tryed on computer with 4 cores, and it still was using only one. I guess this is some how related to ARM emulator implementation. BTW, emulator especially slow for me when I debug.

Comment: I tried running the X86 Port on VMware , runs very fast , but does not connect to my network :(. I would also like to add that the emulator always is slow for me , I run an i7 and the dev kit is still faster than the emulator for cpu extensive purposes

Answer (score 5):

Why not just plug in an Android powered phone?  Just set USB debugging on and it acts exactly like the emulator.

I have run the Android-x86 project on my n450 powered netbook and it was unusable.  The port is by no means ready for daily use.  Basically, if you think the emulator is slow, you will cry when you find out how slow Android-x86 is.  My advice would be to throw a few bucks at a newer/faster computer if you think the emulator is slow.  I develop on a 3 year old Core2Duo 2.4Ghz notebook and it runs just fine.  I've even run the x86 port on the same notebook and it's horribly slow (not to mention not touchscreen).  Also, if the network doesn't work 'out of the box', then you'll have to hack the source code and implement your own driver as Android-x86 is meant to work on Asus Eee PCs.

So either upgrade, or plug in your android powered phone and use that.

But for now, I wouldn't bother trying to use the x86 port for development.  It's just not ready yet.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://blog.gokifu.com/2011/05/android-x86-faster-emulator/) you can find a tutorial for installing and connecting to the eclipse x86 version.

Answer (score 2):

if you use eclipse, before running your program, run the virtual device from "Android sdk and virtual device manager". surely you will be excited from fast running.
dont forget to increase your device ram in hardware setting section.

Answer (score 0):

1. When booted, use Alt+F1 to go to terminal.
2. Enter: `netcfg eth0 dhcp`
3. Your network should start and get the Ip, you can check if you run `netcfg`

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I'm getting this annoying error: "action 'dhcp' failed (No such device)"... :(